# Does my file get corrupted if my flashdisk disconnect when moving file?

Tags: hard-drive, file-transfer

I was moving file from my hard disk to my flash disk using the "cut" option , and then suddenly and accidentally plugged out the flash disk. Is my data on my hard drive safe or it is corrupted? And how to know if files on the flash disk is corrupted?

Comment: Does the original file still exist?  [Edit] your question to include this vital information

Answer (score 0):

Normally when using the Windows method of "moving" a file the original file is undamaged until it's successfully copied over.

Sometimes, when a move/copy is interrupted, the destination file still holds the same date/time and size of the original file. This is because it ensures the destination media has enough room first. But the destination file partially contains data from the original file.

So you can use any type of tool to compare files at the data level. First thing that comes to mind are MD5 comparing tools. Generate hash codes for each file and compare them, if they are different then the files are different.

If it's a text file, you can use KDiff3.

If you want to compare down to the binary level, you could use "hexcompare"

I also use FreeFileSync, this copying tool will compare your source folder against your destination folder at different level (size, size & date/time, file content) and provides fail over copy.